# d3js - i want to see lines

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a project using d3js platform.

but when i customermized d3js's file and json file,

```js
var diameter = 960,
  radius = diameter / 2,
  innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.cluster().size([360, innerRadius]);

var line = d3.radialLine().curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85)).radius(
  function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }).angle(function(d) {
  return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", diameter).attr(
  "height", diameter).append("g").attr("transform",
  "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".node");

var classes = [{
    "name": "LineOne.Seoul",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne.Cityhall",
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "station": "1호선.종로3가",
      "value": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineOne.Cityhall",
    "size": 3812,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne .Seoul",
      "value": 3000
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineOne.Jongro-3",
    "size": 3812,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne.Seoul",
      "value": 3500
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineOne.Jongro-5",
    "size": 38120,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne.Seoul",
      "value": 40000
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineOne.DongDaeMoon",
    "size": 1812,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne.Seoul",
      "value": 3500
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "LineOne.DongMyo",
    "size": 28120,
    "imports": [{
      "station": "LineOne.Seoul",
      "value": 25000
    }]
  }
];

var root = packageHierarchy(classes).sum(function(d) {

  return d.size;
});


cluster(root);
var index_size = 0;

link = link.data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) {
    console.log("link : " + d)
    d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1];
  })
  .attr("class", "link").attr("d", line).style("stroke", function(d) {


    if (d[0].value < 2000) {
      return "red";
    } else if (d[0].value >= 2000 && d[0].value < 10000) {
      return "blue";
    } else if (d[0].value >= 10000) {
      return "black";
    }
  });


node = node.data(root.leaves()).enter().append("text").attr(
  "class", "node").attr("dy", "0.31em").attr(
  "transform",
  function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" +
      (d.y + 8) + ",0)" +
      (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)");
  }).attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
  return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
}).text(function(d) {
  return d.data.key;
}).on("mouseover", mouseovered).on("mouseout", mouseouted);

function mouseovered() {}

function mouseouted() {}

function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {

    var node = map[name],
      i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {
        name: name,
        children: []
      };
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name
          .lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);


      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return d3.hierarchy(map[""]);
}

// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
    imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.data.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.data.imports.station)
      d.data.imports.station.forEach(function(i) {
        imports.push(map[d.data.name].path(map[i]));
      });

  });

  return imports;
}
```

```css
.node {
 font: 300 15px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
 fill: #000;
}

.link {
 stroke: red;
 stroke-opacity: 0.5;
 fill: none;
 pointer-events: none;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}


.node:hover, .node--source, .node--target {
 font-weight: 700;
}

.node--source {
 fill: #2ca02c;
}

.node--target {
 fill: #d62728;
}

.link--source, .link--target {
 stroke-opacity: 1;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
 stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
 stroke: #2ca02c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

there is no graphic lines on the chrome. Only change is 'imports's variable format in json file(Arraylist -> Map). how can i solve the problem?

Comment: would you please be clearer on what it is that you started with and what you changed?  creating a snippet of code that is what you started with and another with what you have now so the difference is clearer, it would be great.  What was the result?  Is there a javascript error?  What is the error?  What is it supposed to look like?  What does it look like?

Comment: The `packageImports` function returns an empty array for the current json data. So zero paths are drawn. And the function expects the `station` attribute to be an array, but json data has different content. You correct all these to plot the chart.

Comment: @Gilsha thx!! I fixed it by using one more forEach method in the .style("stroke-opacity", function(d){ } :)

Comment: @Jose Jimenez thank you for answering the question! I found the error in js. problem is data type was not matched!